# How to change the colour of top bar of Form in windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms

im making a chess game, and  the big white bar at the top of my board hurts my eyes so i wanna make it darker, dunno how tho[picture of designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBf5Y.png)

i tried searching it up and messing about with different commands expecting the bar to change but it didnt, might just be dumb tho